# Symfony2 : using assets in sub-layout templates

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm working on a Symfony2 application and I'm trying to import resources (here, css and js) in a specifig twig template, instead of in the layout templates. However, what I've tried doesn't seem to work when I use the extends property. Yet it **does** work when there is no layout inheritance.

Here's the code I used :

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets 'bundles/mybundlename/css/style.css'
                    filter='cssrewrite' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" />
    {% endstylesheets %} 
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts 'bundles/mybundlename/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'
                'bundles/mybundlename/js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js'
                        %}
        <script src='{{ asset_url }}' type='text/javascript'></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}

{% extends "MyBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

... the rest of my template ...
```

Bottom line, how would I import those resources in my inheriting template?
Or is it simply better to just import them in the general layout (but then it loads for every page :/) ?

Edit : I have used @MyBundle route types as well, and they are being searched by the engine (if the path is wrong, I get an error), but the resources are not added the the html  section.

Second edit : The reason why it was not working is likely that I hadn't declared the `{{% blocks %}}` in my top level layout. I did and used {{ parent() }} (as a matter of "cleanliness") in my sub layouts and pages, and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{% extends ... %}` must come first.

You might also want to use the [`parent`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/parent.html) function to append to the stylesheets and javascripts defined in the layout instead of overwriting them.

Comment: I actually tried both, but as I just edited, the resources are being searched, but not actually loaded in the page.

Comment: Then you have a problem somewhere else. My point is that it *is* possible to do what you want.

Comment: Troubleshot it : if the `{% blocks %}` are not defined in the top-level layout, they are not imported in the layouts that inherit from them. Using the `{{ parent() }}` method works very well once those blocks are defined. Thank you! By the way, I've made a chat room for Symfony2, if you work with it as well... well, just sayin' :)